React Checkbox Change Handler Slowing Down Performance
I'm currently working on a React project where I have a table with thousands checkboxes representing various questions. Each checkbox has an onChange handler to update the state when clicked. However, I noticed that the performance of my application is suffering when clicking the checkboxes, especially when the table is large.
[Violation] 'click' handler took 1940ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 1830ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 2330ms

Here's a simplified version of my component structure:
// ChecklistTPM.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ChecklistRowTPM from "./ChecklistRowTPM";

function ChecklistTPM({ list, onUpdate, planning, Visibility }) {
  const handleCheckboxChange = (tableIndex, questionIndex, demeriteValue, subIndex) => {
    setChecklist(prevChecklist => produce(prevChecklist, draft => {
      // Accessing the question directly in the draft (mutably)
      const question = draft.Tables[tableIndex].questions[questionIndex];
      
      // Mutating the question's demerite directly
      question.demerite = question.demerite === demeriteValue ? "-1" : demeriteValue;
      
      // Conditionally accessing and mutating sub-questions if they exist
      if (question.sousQuestions && subIndex !== null) {
        const subQuestion = question.sousQuestions[subIndex];
        subQuestion.demerite = subQuestion.demerite === demeriteValue ? "-1" : demeriteValue;
      }
    }));
  };

  return (
    // Rendering code
    <>
      {table.questions.map((question, questionIndex) => (
        <ChecklistRowTPM
          key={`question-${questionIndex}`}
          tableIndex={tableIndex}
          question={question}
          handleCheckboxChange={handleCheckboxChange}
          Visibility={Visibility}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default ChecklistTPM;

Even though I've optimized the rendering of my components and use produce from the Immer library for state updates, there's still a noticeable delay when clicking the checkboxes. The Chrome DevTools show violations like click and message handlers taking a considerable amount of time.
What I Expected:
I expected the checkbox click handlers to update only the clicked checkbox's state, without causing significant performance issues, even in a large table.
What I Tried:
Implementing local component state for each checkbox and using Immer's produce function to update state immutably.
Optimizing the rendering logic and avoiding unnecessary re-renders by using React's memoization techniques.
Reviewing the Chrome DevTools performance analysis to identify bottlenecks, but I couldn't pinpoint the exact cause of the slowdown.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to optimize checkbox click handlers in React to improve performance, especially within a large table? I'm open to alternative approaches or optimizations that can help mitigate the performance issues.
Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
